# Grid csv/excel export not working

Tags: grid, csv, export

I  currently can't export anything in the grids for products, clients and newsletters in my computer (and from another computer in another state). It downloads properly from my phone.

When I click the export from the grid, the files starts to download but takes a long time waiting and finally fails: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHT3I.jpg

After failing, I can see in the network tab of the browsers webdev toolbar the request, and if I export it as a .har, it shows that the file's contents where downloaded.

This fails in Edge, Chrome and FF.

Comment: Which version are you in?

Comment: I am using Magento CE 1.9

Comment: Is there any error messages from `var/log`?

Comment: None. It just fails silently.

Comment: Most likely `memory_limit` of PHP is not enough, try to increase it and retry

Comment: It's not as others can download it just fine, as well as from other devices like my phone and tablet. Just not my computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a CDN, for example CloudFlare CDN, it is advised not to use this on the admin as it will cause problems such as this issue as well as cross-origin problems with editing CMS pages as another example.  This issue CloudFlare says is due to a mismatching in header buffer sizes.

Please use CDN only in website scope, not in the global scope.

You can also get this error if you are using certain proxies or firewall services.  For example Sucuri.net.  Some possible fixes, in this case, are to disable the firewall or disable server-side compression on the webserver, for example, zlib compression and/or gzip compression.  Details on this can be found here:
https://docs.sucuri.net/website-firewall/troubleshooting/failed-network-error-when-downloading-files/